# skip every nth value when looping over a range - python

Tags: python, loops, skip

Let's say I have something like this.

```
for i in range((n**2)+(n-1)):
    print i,
```

Here

`n = any integer after one(2, 3, 4 etc.)`

Now, if `n is 2`, I'll get values of `i` as `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`.

What I need is to be able to skip every nth value of `i` so that, if `n is 2`, my output will be `0, 1, 3, 4` and if `n = 3`, my output will  be `0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10`

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One such way to do that is just skip the iterations of the loop you don't want to iterate with a continue statement

```
for i in range(0,11):
    if i % 3 == 0 and i != 0:
        continue
    print(i)


1
2
4
5
7
8
10
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there is a difference between your output in the output I need. I don't want to skip multiples of 'n' from my code. Instead, I want to skip every nth occurrence of i.

Comment: Please update your question to correctly reflect what you are looking for.  Skipping every nth value implies that you want to skip not just  the first instance, but every nth instance as shown in my sample.   If you just want to skip the first nth instance the code can be modified to accommodate that as well

Comment: sorry if my question wasn't clear to you. I'm new to python and am not familiar with all the technical terms. However, if you look at the examples I've provided in my question, you can understand what I'm looking for. Anyways, based on the idea you gave me, I've found out the solution I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what Brian Cain said, I have found the solution for my question. Thanks Brian. The following is the code I was looking for:

```
for i in range ((n**2)+(n-1)):
    if (i+1) % (n+1) == 0 and i != 0:
        continue
    print i
```

Comment: @cricket_007 I have accepted Brian's answer. That's what helped me get what I wanted and I have acknowledged that in my answer too. But, don't I have to post the exact solution for my problem in case someone comes here with this same question, instead of just letting them figure out everything? I thought that was the procedure in this site. I'll delete my answer if you think I'm wrong.

Comment: you can keep your answer,but you haven't accepted the other answer. To do that click the checkmark under the arrows on the left of the answer.

Comment: @cricket_007 my bad. I didn't know I could do that. Thanks for letting me know about this. Will be so helpful in the future.

Comment: not a problem, welcome to StackOverflow. You can also upvote any answers you find helpful.